# Remove Quantity number before stock status in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i use plugin called [WC Product Stock Status](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-product-stock-status/) into [my Woocommerce site](https://www.fruit.co.il/en/catalog/ananas-comosus/), and want to remove number before stock status. I tryed to see if quantity number is set in different CSS class, but seems that is all in one class, so hidding via CSS looks not possible.

```
.woocommerce div.product p.stock
{font-size: .92em;}
.woocommerce div.product .s_in_stock_color {
color:#77a464;
}
```

Unfortinally this plugin is outdated and looks no longer supported be author, so asking question on plugin page, is useless. So i want just to remove number of quantity that is in stock, and keep the label, like on image bellow:

[image]

I checked into code and found that that table is generated fetching this data in **class-variable-status.php** file:

```
 public function print_stock_status(){
    global $product; 

    if($product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
        $childrens = $product->get_children();
        $values = array();
        foreach($childrens as $child){
            $prod = wc_get_product($child);
            $search_replace = array();
            $search_replace['%formatted_name%'] = $prod->get_formatted_name();
            $search_replace['%name%'] = wc_get_formatted_variation($prod);
            $search_replace['%sku%'] = $prod->get_sku();
            $search_replace['%id%'] = $prod->get_id();

            $format = wc_pstocks_option('variable_title');
            $format = str_replace(array_keys($search_replace),array_values($search_replace),$format);
            $status = $prod->get_availability();;
            $status['title'] = $format;
            $status['ID'] = $child;
            $status['formatted_name'] = $prod->get_formatted_name();
            $status['name'] = wc_get_formatted_variation($prod);
            $status['sku'] = $prod->get_sku();
            $status['id'] = $prod->get_id(); 
            $values[$child] = $status; 
        } 

        $this->generate_table($values);
    } 
}
 public function generate_table($values){
    wc_pstocks_get_template('stock-variation- 
table.php',array("args"=>$values));
}
```

and this is code **from stock-variation- 
    table.php**

```
<?php

    foreach($args as $arr){ 
        $text = empty($arr['availability']) ? '' : '<p class="stock '.esc_attr($arr['class']).'">'.$arr['availability'].'</p>'; 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$arr['title'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$text.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>'; 
    }

?>
```

I think that something neeed to be updated into this line:

```
            $text = empty($arr['availability']) ? '' : '<p class="stock '.esc_attr($arr['class']).'">'.$arr['availability'].'</p>';
```

Any help how to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix myself.. This is what i do:

1. From Woocommerce settings goes to Products>Inventory and just set this:

[image]

Now showing statuses, but without quantity.